# Does opensolaris support Solaris9 branded zones?

Tags: solaris, opensolaris, zones

I have a Sun t1000 pre installed with Solaris 10 6/06. Branded zones didn't come to Solaris 10 until a later revision.

With Oracle changing the Solaris license to require a support contract after 90 days i am considering running opensolaris instead.

My main requirement is to be able to run multiple solaris9 sparc instances on this t1000.

Does opensolaris support Solaris9 branded zones?

Cheers,

ram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I regret but it seems not to be supported yet. I found only two brands in the OpenSolaris kernel code, they are solaris10 and sn1 (used for debugging):

http://src.opensolaris.org/source/xref/onnv/onnv-gate/usr/src/uts/common/brand/